# Line Integral help

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

When a==a,

```
Clear["Global`*"];
c[t_] := {a*Cos[t], a*Sin[t]};
vf = {y^2, 0};
Integrate[vf.Dt[{x, y}, t] /. Thread[{x, y} -> c[t]], {t, 0, Pi},Assumptions-> a>0]

(* Integrate returns unevaluated. *)
```

When a==2, I can get the result.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
c[t_] := {2*Cos[t], 2*Sin[t]};
vf = {y^2, 0};
Integrate[vf.Dt[{x, y}, t] /. Thread[{x, y} -> c[t]], {t, 0, Pi}]

(*-(32/3)*)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Mathematica not easy to handle differential form. Here we use traditional form.

```
c[t_] = {a*Cos[t], a*Sin[t]};
vf = {y^2, 0};
Integrate[c'[t] . vf /. Thread[{x, y} -> c[t]], {t, 0, Pi}]
```

> `-((4 a^3)/3)`

- Another way is set `Constants -> {a}` in `Dt`.

```
c[t_] := {a*Cos[t], a*Sin[t]};
vf = {y^2, 0};
Integrate[
 vf . Dt[{x, y}, t, Constants -> {a}] /. Thread[{x, y} -> c[t]], {t, 
  0, Pi}, Assumptions -> a > 0]
```

> `-((4 a^3)/3)`

Comment: The answer is great. Thanks a lot!! @cvgmt